# Not having sex with wife for 1 year since marraige and when asked she refuse

Tags: nikah, sex, wife, life

Asslam o alikum,
I have been married with my wife 2 years ago and since our first night we don't have been physical with each other. She asked me after 6 months about sex and as my father was on dilaysis at that time and in bad condition, I said we will do it later and then after my father's death after that year i started asking her about starting of intercourse but at that she told me she needs time. She said she needs two months i waited two months and then when i asked her again she kept refusing untill today i am looking for a job and now I'm in uae and my wife is in our home coutry.

My question is have I done wrong in such situation?

Comment: Hi Abbas. Please rephrase the question and make it clearer.

Comment: Note that our site is not a peer support. It is the right of your wife to have a happy relationship with her husband it seems that you detained her in first place. And made her unhappy. The fact that you by now lead a distance relationship isn't any better for your spousal relationship.

Comment: Yes u r right but i have never denied the fact i did not love her i lovr her i did want releationship to start i know its my falut from start its her right but i m so much confuse what should i do i have father on dilaysis which i have to take hospital 3 times in a week.my mental suition is so much tense that some time my brain stop working

Answer (score 1):

no, you did nothing wrong, she is your wife, and you had some difficult times, so it's also her duty to understand that and support you and stand by your side, not to act childish like that, after all that's what marriage is all about.

On the other hand leaving things unsolved and going to another country probably wasn't the right move, it may just cpmlicate the situation more, you should also be by her side, talk to her keep trying to make her understand that you love her, that you didn't reject it was just some hard time etc, but now that each one is on a different country it may not be that easy.

May Allah help us all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make wife happy, talk nicely , get good food gifts, get new clothes, tell her she is beautiful , get her makeup. Then take a good shower put perfume on yourself wear clean clothes and sex will happen.
Pray to Allah to guide you. Never make your wife upset or shout at her.
Prayer will help you.